# Core Plot Line Selection

Tags: touch, line, selection, core-plot

I am developing an iOS application that uses the Core Plot framework to plot some data points on a scatter plot along with a trend line.  I would like the user to be able to select not only the data points, but the actual line.  Basically, I need to know when a touch down occurs within, say, 10 points of the line.  Is this possible?  Here is a picture of what I am talking about.

[image]

Comment: I accepted your [enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=572).